# Show coupon value before submitting payment with Charge

Tags: ajax, charge

I'm using Charge to provide a payment mechanism on a website I'm working on. I'm also using the 'coupons' in Charge to provide a means for users to apply a discount to a purchase at the point of payment. However I would like to validate and display the discount on the payment page before the users submits so they can be sure that the discount has been applied.

I have a bespoke module which I am using to create and manage my basket so I'm not adverse to writing a Stripe API call if required but wondered if perhaps I was missing something that's already built into charge by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just went ahead and wrote a small module to handle this...

```
function Checkout_validate_coupon_url() {

    // Construct the ACT URL
    $url = $this->site_url."?ACT=".ee()->functions->fetch_action_id( $this->package_name, 'charge_validate_coupon' );

    return $url;

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

function Charge_validate_coupon() {

    // Check for coupon
    $coupon = ee()->input->get('coupon');
    $price = ee()->input->get('price');

    if (is_null($coupon) OR is_null($price)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!$coupon = ee()->db->where('code', $coupon)->get('charge_coupon')->row_array()) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // New data
    $data = array(
        'price' => $price
        );

    // Percentage_off OR Amount_off
    if ($coupon['type']=="percentage") {
        $data['price_discounted'] = $price - ($price * ($coupon['percentage_off'] / 100));
    } else {
        $data['price_discounted'] = $price - $coupon['amount_off'];
    }

    // If this is an ajax request return a JSON response
    if (ee()->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        ee()->output->send_ajax_response(array(
            'success' => TRUE,
            'data' => $data
            ));
    }

    return $data;

}
```

And then added an AJAX call to my Charge payment form which fired on keyup/blur of the coupon input. :)